How to increase retention period for a custom metric/event in an Azure Application Insights?
I am trying to understand if it is possible to increase retention period for a custom metric/event in an Azure Application Insights?
I want to send my own custom events to an existing Application Insights instance (or perhaps to log analytics workspace directly), and I want to store these metrics for as long as possible, for example 2 years.
I know by default App Insights has a data retention of 30/90 days, and I don't want to change it for all of Application Insights, but just for this new custom metric I am sending is there a way to increase the data retention period?
My Application Insights is using log analytics workspace, and I can see underlying tables have possibility to change their retention period, but I don't understand the connection between my custom events and these tables.

Refer this MSDoc once.

It does not have the answer

I don't see any option to increase the retention period of any particular metric or any event.

AFAIK,Application Insights only supports to change the retention period for the complete Application Insights.


I can see underlying tables have possibility to change their retention period, but I don't understand the connection between my custom events and these tables.

The CustomEvents table in Application Insights can be seen as AppEvents table in Log Analytics Workspace.

It is the same table of your Custom Events/Telemetry.

ApplicationInsights:

Log Analytics Workspace:


So, you can set the retention for the AppEvents table.


